# WPF XAML references not resolved via myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I have a WPF container application (with `ContentControl` host) and a containee application (`UserControl`). Both are oblivious of each other.

Only one XML config file holds the string `dllpath` of the containee's DLL and full namespace name of the `ViewModelClass` inside the containee.

A generic code in container resolves containee's assembly (`Assembly.LoadFrom(dllpath)`) and creates the viewmodel's instance using `Activator.CreateInstance(vmType)`. when this `viewmodel` is hosted inside the `ContentControl` of the container, and relevant vierwmodel specific ResourceDictionary is added to `ContentControl.Resources.MergedDictionaries` of the content control of container, so the view loads fine.

Now my containee has to host the WPF `DataGrid` using assembly reference of `WPFToolkit.dll` from my local `C:\Lib` folder.

The **Copy Local** reference to the `WPFToolkit.dll` is added to the `.csproj` file of the containee's project and its only referred in the `UserControl.XAML` using its XAML namepsace. This way my `bin\debug` folder in my containee application, gets the `WPFToolkit.dll` copied.

**XAML:**

`xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"`
`<Controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AssetList}" ... />`

**Issue:**
The moment the `ViewModel` (i.e. the containee's usercontrol) tries to load itself I get this error.

**"Cannot find type 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid'. The assembly used when compiling might be different than that used when loading and the type is missing."**

Hence I tried to load the referenced assemblies of the containee's assembly (`myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`) before the viewmodel is hosted. **But `WPFToolkit` isnt there in that list of assemblies!**

Strange thing is I have another dll referred called `Logger.dll` in the containee codebase but this one is implemented using C# code behind. So I get its reference correctly resolved in `myAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`.

So does that mean BAML references of assemblies are never resolvable by `GetReferencedAssemblies`?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to add I did a post build event in containee to xcopy all `bin\debug\*.*` to container's 'bin\debug'. It works then. But I dont want all containee's being copied like that to the container. Container should be oblivious of containee applications (even dlls) until runtime.

Comment: For test purpose only try to move `wpfToolkit.dll` to folder where `exe` file is located and see if that solves it. If so your application simply cant find this `dll` so add custom reference resolver by attaching to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and find it yourself.

Comment: Forgot to add I did a post build event in containee to xcopy all `bin\debug\*.*` to container's 'bin\debug'. It works then. But I dont want all containee's being copied like that to the container. Container should be oblivious of containee applications (even dlls) until runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem might be to add handler to [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. This event is called as last resort when an assembly is needed and your application cannot find is in an ordinary way. This is the place where you can customize this process by scanning your containees folders (read from config so no hard relationship) in an attempt to find needed `dll`.

Comment: Thx Rafal. Yes I recreated the references (physcial path i.e. `C:\Lib` and name of referred assembly dll i.e. 'WPFToolkit.dll`) into a `..\containeeApp\bin\debug\containee.dll.config` file and resolved them in this event. **HAVING SAID THAT WE STILL DONT KNOW WHY XAML ASSEMBLY REFERENCES ARE NOT AVAILABLE AT REFLECTION TIME**.